# Open window.location.href value in a new window

Tags: javascript

I have a script that collects a visitor's website URL and appends it to a target URL and opens up a demo of a chatbot.

I want to have the complete URL open in a new window.  I understand that I need to use window.open to open the URL in a new window.

I do not know how to pass the appended value of the window.location.href through to the window.open command.  Here is the script.

```
<script>
function redirectToDemo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  const urlField = document.querySelector('input[name="urlInput"]');
  const websiteUrl = urlField.value;
  if(!websiteUrl.trim()){
    return false;
  }
  window.location.href = `https://demo.sndrmsg.com?url=${encodeURIComponent(websiteUrl)}`;
  return false;
}
```

I have gone through numerous previous answers and cannot figure out how to get things to work properly.

Comment: Setting `window.location.href` immediately redirects the user to the URL. You probably want to do ``window.open(`https://demo.sndrmsg.com?url=${encodeURIComponent(websiteUrl)}`);`` instead of setting `window.location.href`

Comment: Thank you Heretic Monkey!  That did the trick.  I appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the URL parameter from **window.location.href** and then use it with **window.open**

```js
function redirectToDemo(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  const urlField = document.querySelector('input[name="urlInput"]');
  const websiteUrl = urlField.value.trim();

  if (!websiteUrl) {
    return false;
  }

  const demoUrl = `https://demo.sndrmsg.com?url=${encodeURIComponent(websiteUrl)}`;

  window.open(demoUrl, "_blank");

  return false;
}
```